# How do I determine what device drivers I need from command line?

Tags: drivers, device-manager, windows-pe, winpe

I need network access from a device running [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment), but I don't believe that the WinPE image has the correct network drivers. Is there a way to figure out what drivers I need from the command line?

I don't have access to documentation on the device.

Comment: You could use the [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) tool to determine the ID of the NIC and then use the browser to Google for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an application called "[DevManView](http://download.cnet.com/DevManView/3000-2094_4-10973315.html)", and I used that to look at what devices my machine had.